# pg_dump: too many command-line arguments (first is "--host=localhost")

Tags: python, django, postgresql, database-backups

I have gone through some similar question on SO but didn't find any workable solutions.

I tried using `djang-dbbackup` module with my Django project.
I run `$ python manage.py dbbackup` and got this error:

```
CommandConnectorError: Error running:  pg_dump last_cosmetics --host=localhost --username=postgres --no-password --clean 
b'pg_dump: too many command-line arguments (first is "--host=localhost")\r\nTry "pg_dump --help" for more information.\r\n'
```

Also I tried running it on Windows cmd.

```
pg_dump last_cosmetics --host=localhost --username=postgres --no-password --clean
```

But I still get the same error.

Comment: Do we need to have knowledge of **another** question to understand the issue? If not please remove the lines.

Comment: I wanted to say this is not a duplicate question - the recipes under similar questions didn't help me, I have read them all. Why shouldn't I mention that?

Comment: Have you tried this - **pg_dump  --host=localhost --username=postgres --no-password -Fc last_cosmetics**

Comment: tried that command: error `pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "last_cosmetics" failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check syntax in [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-pgdump.html).

Database name should be last argument after all options.

So in your case use:

```
pg_dump --host=localhost --username=postgres --no-password --clean last_cosmetics
```

Comment: yep, you are right. I have also seen that in PostgreSQL docs, tried - and it didn't work. When you wrote - I have tried again, restarted postgresql server - and that worked from Windows cmd. But the question is - why django-dbbackup module sends a wrong command? How to fix that? Thank you anyway.

Comment: What is wrong for my command then? `pg_dump -c -C -f ./cypress/db_dump.sql -p 5433 -h 127.0.0.1 -U odoo -W odoo -d odoo`

Comment: @tom10271 I believe you unnecessarily flag the database name with the `-d`, should just be `pg_dump -c -C -f ./cypress/db_dump.sql -p 5433 -h 127.0.0.1 -U odoo -W odoo odoo`

Answer (score 0):

If you used user as `postgres` in CentOS then

```
su postgres
pg_dump -Fc last_cosmetics > /tmp/last_cosmetics.dump
```

It works in Ubuntu too.